# Can Dynamodb Global secondary indexes (GSIs) return attributes from base table (bookmark lookup)?

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb

We say that GSIs does not have to include the partition key of base table, and GSIs can have a different partition key as base table, so i am wondering there is no way for a GSI to return attribute from base table that are not included in the GSI? Is my understanding right? For example  if a query find a GSI useful since it sorted on column the query requires but the GSI is missing some attributes that is required by the query, will the GSI be of any use to the query or cannot be used due to missing attributes?

I am thinking GSIs cannot return attributes that are not included within GSI

Answer (score 0):

First of all a GSI must always include the partition key of the base table, the minimum projection type is `KEYS_ONLY`.

But you are correct, if an attribute does not exist in a GSI, then it cannot obtain that value from the base table.

In contrast, a Local Secondary Index (LSI) can obtain attributes which are not projected into the index, at an additional read cost, but all within a single request. However, with an LSI you cannot change the partition key, only the sort key, and thus its not as flexible.

Comment: However, the GSI is still "useful" since the app can then GET from the base table using the keys returned; which is likely to be more efficient than SCANing the base table.  It's also unclear if the OP understands that all attributes from the base table can be projected to the GSI.